# Use mobile OS specific widgets

Tags: angular, nativescript

In my application, I need a sidedrawer. At first I thought using the [plugin from Telerik](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples) which includes a sidedrawer. But then I found out [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/issues/71) it wasn't possible to use this plugin in a Nativescript/Angular 2 project yet. Then I found out about the [placeholder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder) in Nativescript which allows to use iOS/Android native widgets.

So for the sidedrawer, I thought I could use the [Navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) from Android but the typescript compiler (tsc) sends me an error telling me it doesn't recognize the name 'android' (see link about placeholder).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you received this error after attempted build or just in the typescript intellisense!? If you are talking about the intellisense error " Cannot find name 'android' " you should just ignore it - your project will build with no problem and you will have access to the natie APIs from Android and iOS.

Comment: I have that error when I type the command 'tsc' in the console.

Comment: can you please share some more info with us... for example the command you are running and some of the code you are trying to build

Comment: This is the [view](http://pastebin.com/wVejVmLJ) of my page : I have 3 different tabs (Accueil [Home in French], Notifications and Messages). In the code, you'll see where I want to put the side drawer. According to [Nativescript](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder), there is an attribute "creatingView" which is linked to a function in a component (see the Nativescript link). In my case, I want the [android navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and even though I follow the exact instructions, I have nothing.

Comment: And as you said, when I run the command "tns run android" or " tns livesync android", the error about "Cannot fin name android" is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic implementation of the native Android Drawer Layout as a side-drawer.

In your page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
     <Placeholder creatingView="creatingView"/>
</Page>
```

In you page.js

```
var app = require("application");
var drawer;
var page;
var appContext;
function navigatingTo(args) {
    page = args.object;
    appContext = app.android.context;
}
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;

function creatingView(args) {
    // init DrawerLayout
    drawer = new android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout(appContext);
    var frame = new android.widget.FrameLayout(appContext);

    // here you can use ListView with Adapters if you prefer
    var linearMenu = new android.widget.LinearLayout(appContext);
    linearMenu.setOrientation(1);

    // adding the menu options
    var textView1 = new android.widget.TextView(appContext);
    textView1.setText("ITEM 1");
    var textView2 = new android.widget.TextView(appContext);
    textView2.setText("ITEM 2");
    var textView3 = new android.widget.TextView(appContext);
    textView3.setText("ITEM 3");

    // setting layout params
    var lp = new android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(100,        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.gravity = android.view.Gravity.START;

    linearMenu.setLayoutParams(lp);
    linearMenu.addView(textView1);
    linearMenu.addView(textView2);
    linearMenu.addView(textView3);

    // finally adding the elements to the DrawerLayout and attaching it to the NativeScript placeholder
    drawer.addView(frame, new  android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.Layou tParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    drawer.addView(linearMenu);
    args.view = drawer;
}
exports.creatingView = creatingView;
```

This is a very basic example with no transition effects and no vent listeners attached but still will work with swipe as a demonstration how to use the native APIs to create a drawer in {N} - hope that helps you in your project.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well I tried your code and I'm sure it works but since I'm developing using Nativescript AND Angular 2, I guess there are some differences (well I'm pretty sure I can use the function creatingView as you typed it) because right now I still don't get anything on the page. 
And thank you for your time